# Установка свойств наследников стандартных элементов (например, FlowLayoutPanel)

Tags: c#, winforms

При наследовании, например, от FlowLayoutPanel, в конструкторе прописываю свойства:

```
class myFlow : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public myFlow()
    {
        AutoSize = true;
        AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    }
}
```

в дизайнере кидаю этот элемент на форму и, например, хочу вернуть обратно AutoSize=false. Вроде бы меняется и выглядит элемент на форме как нужно, но после ребилда и закрытия-открытия дизайнера формы свойство снова имеет значение, прописанное в конструкторе. Пробовал override InitLayout, но эффект тот же.
Как правильно настраивать компоненты, чтобы в дизайнере можно было их поменять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),DefaultValue(true)
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.AutoSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.AutoSize = value;
        }
    }
```

Подсмотрел этот код в исходниках Panel от которого у FlowLayoutPanel наследуется свой AutoSize. 
Параметр DefaultValue(true) который собственно и делает то, что вам нужно добавил уже сам... Его существование и возможность использования подглядел в тех же исходниках Panel

AutoSizeMode думаю по аналогии должно сработать... 
Для корректной работы понадобится `using System.ComponentModel;`

Соответственно из конструктора установку значений данных свойств нужно удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Вопрос первый - неужели для всех свойств, которые я буду задавать (а их довольно много - хочу определить свой стиль отображения для однообразия) нужно прописывать такой код? Второй вопрос - где посмотрели исходники? было бы полезно и самому взглянуть

Comment: 1) Ну, походу да.
2) Загрузил сборку в которой находится Panel в dotPeek и там смотрел. (подойдёт, я думаю, любой декомпилятор для .net)

Comment: @kvvk 1)не обязательно, можно же и свое свойство добавить, например Style и в зависимости от его значения выставлять параметры остальных свойств не переопределяя все и вся 2) исходники можно посмотреть и тут http://referencesource.microsoft.com/